# popup form using html/javascript/css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to open an html form in a popup. Popup should not be a window (that is usually created using window.open() ), instead it should  be like one appeared in the link below (open in firefox)
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt
But the problem with this code is that, I cannot change the content popup content from "Please enter your name" to my html form.
While searching, I found that there we CANNOT change the content of popup Prompt Box and the only solution is to create your own popup...
Isn't there any easier solution ?

Thank you....

Comment: Google "Javascript Modals" or "JQuery Modals"

Comment: I believe the "cannot change the [popup] content" comment is referring to _redirect-preventing_ popups.  This message is typically overwritten by browsers for obvious security reasons.  Here's a fiddle illustrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/k2fYM/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please try [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Here is the [forms demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

For mobile use, have a look at [jQuery Mobile - Creating dialogs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-dialogs.html)

Comment: but here comes one more problem. actually i am making the website for mobile browsers. I got the pop-up working on laptops using jquery (as you suggested), but now when I tried to test it on an android mobile, the page did not open. I have posted this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292647/jquery-code-is-not-running-on-android-phone . Can you help me out now...

Answer (score 17):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/rxGmk/)**

Sounds like you might want a light box,and since you didnt tag your question with jQuery included is a pure JS example of how to make one.

**JS**

```
var opener = document.getElementById("opener");

opener.onclick = function(){

    var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox"),
        dimmer = document.createElement("div");

    dimmer.style.width =  window.innerWidth + 'px';
    dimmer.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
    dimmer.className = 'dimmer';

    dimmer.onclick = function(){
        document.body.removeChild(this);   
        lightbox.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    document.body.appendChild(dimmer);

    lightbox.style.visibility = 'visible';
    lightbox.style.top = window.innerHeight/2 - 50 + 'px';
    lightbox.style.left = window.innerWidth/2 - 100 + 'px';
    return false;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<div id="lightbox">Testing out the lightbox</div>
<a href="#" id="opener">Click me</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#lightbox{
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    background:red;
    border:2px solid #3c3c3c;
    color:white;
    z-index:100;
    width: 200px;
    height:100px;
    padding:20px;
}

.dimmer{
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: .5;
    top: 0;
    z-index:99;
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution not using JQuery, and this got me started on the path I wanted to pursue.  Thanks for the post!

Comment: Awesome :) glad it helped you out.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. For anyone trying to adapt this to an existing app: The only two important pieces of the `#lightbox` class are `position:absolute;` and `z-index:100`. Without those two, the popup will actually be below the dimmer.

Answer (score 1):

> But the problem with this code is that, I cannot change the content popup content from "Please enter your name" to my html form.

Umm. Just change the string passed to the `prompt()` function.

> While searching, I found that there we CANNOT change the content of popup Prompt Box

You can't change the **title**. You can change the content, it is the first argument passed to the `prompt()` function.

Comment: But the prompt does not take html, only text

Answer (score 0):

Just replacing "Please enter your name" to your desired content would do the job.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Look at easiest example to create popup using css and javascript.

1. Create HREF link using HTML.
2. Create a popUp by HTML and CSS
3. Write CSS
4. Call JavaScript mehod

See the full example at this link
http://makecodeeasy.blogspot.in/2012/07/popup-in-java-script-and-css.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for a way that is easy to make dialog, please reference the [dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog#advanced_example).

### Other Example

```html
<button id="btn-login">Click me to open the dialog</button>
<dialog style="width:50vw">
  <header>Login</header>
  <form>
    <input id="input-username" type="text" minlength="5" placeholder="username"><br>
    <input id="input-password" type="password" minlength="3" placeholder="password"><br>
    <input type="submit"> <button id="btn-cancel">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</dialog><br>
<output></output>
<script>
  const dialog = document.querySelector(`dialog`)
  const form = dialog.querySelector(`form`)
  const btnLogin = document.querySelector(`#btn-login`)
  const inputUsername = document.querySelector(`#input-username`)
  const inputPassword = document.querySelector(`#input-password`)
  const btnCancelDialog = document.querySelector(`#btn-cancel`)
  const output = document.querySelector(`output`)
  btnLogin.onclick = () => {
    form.reset()
    dialog.showModal()
  }
  btnCancelDialog.onclick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    output.innerHTML = ""
    dialog.close()
  }
  form.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    [username, password] = [inputUsername.value, inputPassword.value]
    output.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify({username, password})}</pre>`
    dialog.close()
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty available. Try using Modal windows of Jquery or DHTML would do good. Put the content in your div or Change your content in div dynamically and show it to the user. It won't be a popup but a modal window.
Jquery's [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) would clear your problem.