# jquery code is not running on android phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a pop-up form for my mobile web page. It is working perfectly on firefox of my laptop. But when I test the page from an android browser, it's just showing an empty page. Please help me out how can I make my web-page suitable for mobile phones?
Link of my code is http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5420677/myfile.html
To see it, also extract this file into the same folder :
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5420677/js.zip

A pop-up form is appearing from firefox, but now on android's browser.
When I remove the line no 5,6 and 7, it becomes accessible from android also, but then obviously pop-up functionality disappears, which suggests that javascript is creating some problem...

Thank you.

FYI, 5,6 and 7th lines are

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: FYI, 5,6 and 7th lines are :
<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

For mobile use, have a look at [jQuery Mobile - Creating dialogs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-dialogs.html)

Comment: opera mobile emulator is getting crashed, when i click on the link which uses these jquery code

Comment: @Arjun - Click the "Open Dialog" button. It is a full screen "pop-up".