# JavaScript interactive form in alert box?

Tags: javascript, forms, alert

Is it possible to put a form into an alert box and then display that to the user? Afterwards I would want to submit the data but I presume it would work the same via a 'POST' method or such.

I had a quick play around but couldn't get it to work, not much on search engines either.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alert box is not editable. You can use javascript to create a new browser window with your form in it.

General form is like this: `window.open('url to open','window name')`
You will fall foul of popup blockers if you handle 'when' you do this badly.

This is quite a nice simple walk through with live examples http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery UI's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). This allows you to turn a DIV into a pop-up box.

Comment: I would be cautious of diving into JQuery right off the bat. It would be better, if something simple is being done, to stay with raw js.

Comment: raw js is what I am using, but would like to thank ced-b for this, it might come in use later...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you jquery shadow: http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/650/jQuery-Custom-PopUp-Window.html

Or if you want you can develop your own form (html, design, css, javascript).

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a single input, you can use [the built-in prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.prompt) method.

Otherwise, you would have to [pop up your own form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265574/popup-form-using-html-javascript-css).

Comment: I did not know about the built-in prompt. I have learnt something - thank you. Is that 'recommended'?

Comment: @CodeBeard It's just a tool that you can use. It has been around a long time and is supported in all browsers (disabled by default in IE7 only), although it isn't part of the DOM standard.