# a form ve to popup while click a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button in a page. What I need is a form to popup on the same page when that button is clicked. The form should contain some fields (name, age, DOB, mail) and a submit button.

Is JavaScript enough to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265574/popup-form-using-html-javascript-css

Comment: This tutorial might help: [HTML Form Tutorial](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-tutorial-p1.phtml)

Comment: What do you want to do with the data itself? Because perhaps you need a server side language also.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely Yes. Its possible with pure JavaScript and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a form inside a `<div>` and hide the whole div during page load using the css properties `display:none`. Then on clicking of the button you can use javascript to show the whole div.